# iAd Test App is missing from the iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, iad

I ran into a strange issue - iAd Tester app is no longer present in iPhone Simulator so I can't test iAds on it. I am using  Xcode 3.2.4 with iOS 4.1 and iAd Framework 1.1.1. I tried re-installing the whole thing (Xcode and iAd package) and resetting the content of the simulator using command from the menu and manually deleting everything from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`.

I think this happened after updating to latest Xcode a few weeks  ago when everything worked fine. Any suggestions guys on where I am going  wrong or missing something?

Developer Information:

```
Version: 3.2 (10M2309)
Location: /Developer
Applications:
Xcode: 3.2.4 (1708)
Interface Builder: 3.2.4 (804)
Instruments: 2.7 (3014)
Dashcode: 3.0.2 (333)
SDKs:
Mac OS X:
10.5: (9L31a)
10.6: (10M2309)
iPhone OS:
3.2: (7B500)
4.1: (8B117)
iPhone Simulator:
3.2: (7W367a)
4.0: (8A306)
4.1: (8B117)
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching the hardware version on the iPhone Simulator:
Hardware -> Version -> 4.0.1

You may lose all of your organizational folders but once I did this I found the iAd Tester app.

Comment: Stephen, you are the best. I tried this before but probably didn't look accurately enough. Just checked again and it is there on the second page. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes the Apple server is just variable in serving test ads.    I have an app that serves test ads sometimes in the simulator but at other times never loads them.   Perhaps this is Apple's way of testing the code so that it responds appropriately to errors.

Comment: Thanks for your your response. My issue is not that I can't test my specific iAd - I can't test any iAds at all because the iAd Test Application is missing from my iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

same thing is happening to me.  my colleague at work can see the iAd Test app, but he has a lower version of the iPhone simulator.  Not sure how to downgrade though.

...edit...

found the app, it's on "page 2".  obviously I am new to iphones, let alone iphone dev.

switching the OS as described in the other answer was necessary for me too

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem. Sometime my app doesn't display Ad correctly. But I post to AppStore, it passed the review process and I can see some requests from America.

You can see it with the link: http://itunes.apple.com/ie/artist/tubiv/id383457772